# Print largest count from each column in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
$chunk  = 4; 

$arr    = array('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1');
```

I modified this array into rows and columns based on the `$chunk`. In this example it would be a 4x4 rows and columns.

What I'd like to do is how to count how many '1' or '0' in every column and print the largest output from either '1' or '0'.

Example:

```
1110
1101
1110
1001

there are 4 number '1' in first column, so the output should be 4
```

My current code:

```
function array_chunk_vertical($arr, $percolnum){
$n = count($arr);
$mod    = $n % $percolnum;
$cols   = floor($n / $percolnum);
$mod ? $cols++ : null ;
$re     = array();
for($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++){
    for($row = 0; $row < $percolnum; $row++){
        if($arr){
            $re[$row][]   = array_shift($arr);
        }
    }
}
return $re;
}

$result = array_chunk_vertical($arr, $chunk);
$new    = 0;
$exist  = 0;

foreach($result  as $row){
    foreach($row as $val){
        if($val == "1"){
            $new++;
        }
        else{
            $exist++;
        }
            echo $val;          
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Your desired output is not clear.  The first column has four `1`s in it -- so show that count.  The second column has three `1`s in it, so show that.  But in the third column, there are two `0`s and two `1`s -- what is the desired output for that? What if the fourth column had three `0`s -- would `3` zeros be the desired printed outcome?  You have answers below which do different things because your question is not precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr    = array('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1');

// Split your array in chunks
$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 4);
// Max counts for 1 and 0 
$max1 = $max0 = 0;
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    // count number of occurences of 1 and 0
    $countedValues = array_count_values($chunk);
    $cur1 = isset($countedValues[1]) ? $countedValues[1] : 0;
    $cur0 = isset($countedValues[0]) ? $countedValues[0] : 0;

    echo 'count 1 is ' . $cur1 . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'count 0 is ' . $cur0 . PHP_EOL;
    
    $max1 = max($max1, $cur1);
    $max0 = max($max0, $cur0);
}

echo '1 max count is ' . $max1 . PHP_EOL . '0 max count is ' . $max0;
```

Comment: Maybe [something more compact](https://3v4l.org/RiV6Y).

Answer (score 2):

Very short snippet to help you out with result.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($result as $k => $v){
    $temp[$k] = count(array_filter(array_column($result,$i)));
    $i++;
}
```

In above code, [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) will fetch data from all the arrays with 0th index, 1st index, and so on.
[array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will remove 0 values(default nature).
Below output consist of count of all the 1st vertically.

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e4e810a80c1192a6f9478e49723d6fb3094b939)

Answer (score 1):

You can count the column `1` and `0` counting by modifying your last foreach loop as follow

```
$columns = array();
 foreach($result  as $row){
   foreach($row as $key => $val){
    $columns[$key][] = $val;
    if($val == "1"){
        $new++;
    }
    else{
        $exist++;
    }
        echo $val;          
   }
  echo '<br/>';
 }

$cols = array_map(function($v){
   $temp = array_count_values($v);
   return 'Element :'.array_keys($temp, max($temp))[0].' came '.max($temp).' times.';
 }, $columns);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($cols);
```

Result

```
Array
(
 [0] => Element :1 came 4 times.
 [1] => Element :1 came 3 times.
 [2] => Element :1 came 2 times.
 [3] => Element :0 came 3 times.
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the chunk method to simplify it a bit and then from this result I use a combination of `array_column()` and `array_sum()` to add up the totals for each column.  You then can use `max()` to find the highest (comments also in code)...

```
$chunk  = 4;
$arr    = array('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1');

function array_chunk_vertical($arr, $percolnum){
    $re = [];
    foreach ( $arr as $number => $value )   {
        // Use modulus % to put value in correct column
        $re [$number % $percolnum][] = $value;
    }
    return $re;
}
$result = array_chunk_vertical($arr, $chunk);

$count = [];
// Loop over first row of output
foreach($result[0]  as $column => $row){
    // Sum up the results of taking all the column values for this column
    $count[$column] = array_sum(array_column($result, $column));
}
// Extract highest
$highest = max($count);
// Find highest and output which one it is.
echo $highest ." in ". (array_search($highest, $count)+1);
```

results in

```
4 in 1
```